# how to make a web site remeber the pages you have visited dynamically?

Tags: web, visited

Hello I wonder if anyone can help me.  I am trying to put together a sidebar nav for my site. basically I am trying to get it to remember the products each user looks at and then display 3 latest one to them. I am not not sure what language is best for it and how to approach this.

Example:

You have visited:

item 1, 
item 2,
item x

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Save it (last visited page) in cookies

On classic ASP. Of course on **each** page you should store previously visited page (in fact it's current page)

```
<%@LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT%>
<%
    '### Get previously visited page
    Response.Write "Last page with params " & Request.Cookies("LastPageWithParams")

    '### Store previously (current) visited page
    Response.Cookies("LastPageWithParams") = Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") & "?" & Request.QueryString

    '### Set expiration as we needed
    Response.Cookies("LastPageWithParams").Expires=#Jan 1,2015#
%>
```

Comment: could elaborate on that a little bit please.  code example would be much appreciated.